# Store Output into Variable with a Function

Tags: bash

So I have a question.  I managed to go get this to work below.

```
main () {
  file="$1"
  if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then echo "$2" > $1; fi
}

main /var/store/traefik.provider NOT-SET
main /var/store/server.email NOT-SET
main /var/store/traefik.domain NOT-SET
main /var/store/tld.program NOT-SET

# Recall Variables - tld - provider - domain - email
provider=$(cat /var/store/traefik.provider)
tld=$(cat /var/store/tld.program)
domain=$(cat /var/store/traefik.domain)
email=$(cat /var/store/server.email)
```

In reality, I'm trying to make code work like this by adding a $3.  The problem I run into that I cannot store a variable into $3.  I get:

```
provider=NOT-SET: command not found
```

As you can see below, I'm trying to recall a variable and store it into the $3 so it's not lengthy up top.  Would you have any suggestions?

```
main () {
  file="$1"
  if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then echo "$2" > $1; fi
  $3=(cat $2)
}

main /var/store/traefik.provider NOT-SET provider
main /var/store/server.email NOT-SET email
main /var/store/traefik.domain NOT-SET domain
main /var/store/tld.program NOT-SET program
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you really want to create a file with `NOT-SET`, try one of these:

```
main() {
   local file=$1 val=$2 var=$3
   [[ -e $file ]] || printf '%s\n' "$val" > "$file"
   printf -v "$var" '%s' "$(<"$file")"
}

main /var/store/traefik.provider NOT-SET provider
```

---

```
main() {
   local file=$1 val=$2
   [[ -e $file ]] || printf '%s\n' "$val" > "$file"
   cat "$file"
}

provider=$(main /var/store/traefik.provider NOT-SET)
```

Comment: Don't use parameter expansion as the first argument to `printf`, as it won't behave as you expect if it contains a `%`. Use the explicit form `printf -v "$var" '%s' "$var" ... ` instead.

Comment: @chepner You are absolutely right, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: The first one worked beautifully.  I struggled with this for awhile.  I have tons of redundant code and this is a huge time saver! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$3=(cat $2)
```

This is invalid. This is wrong syntax. See, the part before `=` is interpreted as variable name and *is not expanded*. A variable name cannot start with `$`.

There maybe many solutions to your problem, bad ones using eval and good ones using other techniques.

Grab a good solution:

```
main() {
  declare -n ref="$3"
  if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then 
     echo "$2" > "$1";
     ref=$2
  fi
}
```

Now the magic is in `-n` switch to `declare` command. From `declare --help`:

```
-n  make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
```

So what happens here, bash interprets the variable value to be a reference to other variable. Thus `ref=$2` automagically set's the variable name `$3` to the value of `$2`.

Let's do a bad solution:

```
main() {
  if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then 
     echo "$2" > "$1";
     eval "$3=\$2"
  fi
}
```

Let's remember that `eval` is [evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). What happens here, is that `"$3=\$2"` is double evaluated, once when passing to `eval`, so it becomes `<the string behind $3>=$2`, then it get's evaluated second time setting the variable.

Comment: You could also mention that `nameref`s require `bash` 4.3 or later :)

Comment: `printf -v "$3" '%s' "$2"` is the safest option. Namerefs are an improvement over `eval`, but aren't bulletproof. See [Bash FAQ 048](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_bash.27s_name_references)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a way to fix the syntax. You *could* use an `eval`, though a `printf -v` is better.

```
$: cat settst
#! /bin/bash
(( $# )) || { echo $0 var val; exit 1; }
setting() {
  eval $1=$2
  printf -v "$2" "%s" "$1"
}
setting $1 $2
set|grep $1=$2
set|grep $2=$1

$: settst foo bar
foo=bar
bar=foo
$: settst x y
x=y
y=x
```

`$3=...` isn't generally valid syntax. By using `eval` that becomes the value of $3 followed by the =, which will be a valid assignment if $3's value is a valid variable name. The `printf -v`, on the other hand, explicitly writes the value to a variable named.

Use the `printf -v "$var" '%s' "$(<"$file")"` syntax [mickp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9136541/mickp) offered, but eval *will* do the job. It will just come back to bite you eventually.

Answer (score 0):

`$3` is the third positional parameter in script context the third argument used to call script, in a function the third argument.

Two options:

- make the logic outside `main` function to add a third argument to `main`
- or use `set` inside the function to set arguments `set -- "$1" "$2" "$(<"$2")"`

Note: once `file` variable assigned with `$1` do not use `$1` any more but use `"$file"`

```
echo "$2" > "$file"
```